# Ranking query not working properly in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

I have this query that is trying to make a ranking from the total number of positive votes, that each user is getting. The problem is that the ranking is made by THE USER ID, not by VOTES. The problem is because of GROUP BY, but I have to use it because one id appears multiple times in `voted_id` section.

I wonder if you have some solutions?

```sql
select 
  a.voted_id, 
 (select 
    count(b.state) 
  from 
   user_vote as b 
  where 
   b.state=1 and b.voted_id=a.voted_id) as votes, 
 @rank:=@rank+1 as ranking from user_vote as a,
 (select @rank:=0)as rank 
where
  a.state=1 
group by 
 a.voted_id 
order by 
 votes asc;
```

So the problem is that ranking is done by `voted_id` not by votes.

Comment: I'm sorry that i cannot post the table structure. I don't have enough reputation

Comment: you can post it via text.. because it's difficult to know what you are trying to do without the table structure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This any good? Little hard to see where you're at without the DDL & some sample data...

```
select voted_id,
       votes,
       @rank:=@rank + 1 as rank
from
(
 select voted_id,count(*) as votes
 from user_vote
 where state=1
 group by voted_id
 order by votes desc
) t
join (select @rank:=0) r;
```

Comment: I don't know how you figured out without the table description, but it worked perfectly.